# why do modern browsers still put spaces between inline block if there is whitespace

Tags: css

If you have markup like this:

```
<div class="inlineblock">one</div>
<div class="inlineblock">two</div>
<div class="inlineblock">three</div>
```

and css like this:
    .inlineblock{ display: inline-block; }

You will get spaces between the elements. about 4px of space. unless your markup looks like this:

```
<div class="inlineblock">one</div><div class="inlineblock">two</div><div class="inlineblock">three</div>
```

Now, what i would like to know is WHY?

What is the technical reason that "good" browsers still do this, even the latest Firefox, Chrome, and Opera at the time of this posting still do this.  I assume there is a technical reason behind it, otherwise it would have been fixed by now?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not? Inline block elements are programmed to appear inline with text. If there's text between, it should be rendered.

Comment: Have not you noticed the fault (actually it is not a failure) in browsed old, why most of them could not stand "inline-block" completely. This is not a failure, I recommend that you use CSS-reset. Read my response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698142/why-do-modern-browsers-still-put-spaces-between-inline-block-if-there-is-whitesp/16698173#16698173

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Don't know why you are making this a discussion about old browsers and their shortcomings. That had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @deweydb I am not making a discussion, I am explaining that this is not a fault. Read my response I edited it.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I don't know why you think a CSS reset has anything to do with the question in any shape or form.  Its not going to make whitespace go away between inline-* elements.  I find it funny that you're trying to support your "use a CSS reset" position with an article that shows why CSS resets are bad.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is exactly what they *should* do.

Spaces between inline elements are no different from spaces between words.

If you don't want that, use block elements, or set the font size to zero.

Comment: Exactly, just like when you do `<span>a</span> <span>b</span>` you expect `a b` and not `ab` and when you write "Hello World" you expect "Hello World" and not "HelloWorld"

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think of it like that, i was mostly thinking of how i hated the look of my markup, but i guess the font size hack will suffice.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are spaces between them!

For a fix, try using `font-size: 0` in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way of removing the white space than setting font size to zero (as that method has unpleasant side effects). You can word-spacing instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

section {
    word-spacing:-.25em; /* hide whitespace nodes in all modern browsers (not for webkit)*/
    display:table;/* Webkit Fix */
}

div {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 40px; 
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    word-spacing:0; /* reset from parent*/
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
</section>          
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is The solution.

```
   <style>
    * {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow:0 0 1px 0px silver;
    }
    .foo {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .bar {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
            ...a new customer
        <!-- the whitespace between the following divs affects rendering - why? -->
        </div> <div class="bar">
            ...an existing customer
        </div>
    </div>
```