# How to remove the default margin of inline li elements?

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML and CSS:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to remove the margin among the li elements by setting `margin: 0;`,  but it doesn't remove the margin.

[image: result of HTML and CSS showing gap]

How do I remove this gap?

Comment: Inline elements respect whitespace. Remove the space in the markup.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/TPje6/2/

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698142/why-do-modern-browsers-still-put-spaces-between-inline-block-if-there-is-whitesp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Combining all `li`s in a single line solves the problem. But if you want to know more techniques to remove those margins you can visit : http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block.

It lists these techniques:

### 1. No Space Between Elements

```
<ul><li>Item content</li><li>Item content</li><li>Item content</li></ul>
```

### 2. font-size: 0 on Parent

```
.inline-block-list { /* ul or ol with this class */
font-size: 0;
}

.inline-block-list li {
font-size: 14px; /* put the font-size back */
}
```

### 3. HTML Comments

```
<ul>
 <li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

### 4. Negative Margin

```
.inline-block-list li {
margin-left: -4px;
}
```

### 5. Dropping Closing Angle

```
<ul>
 <li>Item content</li
 ><li>Item content</li
 ><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Option 2 is most clean way to do it, if you are using visual code or something else, number 1, 3 and 5 can be autoformatted and will not work. As for Nr 4 I do not like negative margins, it causes issues sometimes when zooming the text only.

Answer (score 5):

Try `float: left;` That will force your list items to be rendered without the extra whitespace.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its a weird thing where you need to remove whitespace take a look at this fiddle

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TPje6/3/

another thing you can do is add a `margin: -2px;` : http://jsfiddle.net/TPje6/6/

Float trick works well also, but makes styling a position more difficult

Comment: while that works, try the `font-size` hack I proposed to keep your html readable.

Comment: @Jakub I like the font hack idea, I also like the float idea. So if you have a div container you could just float the elements and they would be in the right position.

Answer (score 3):

This is an annoying side-effect of how the whitespace is being rendered for inline elements. There are a few options that come to mind for addressing it.

**Option 1:**
use the `float: left` property on the `li` elements

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPje6/5/)**</kbd>

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

**Option 2:**
Remove the whitespace from the html markup

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yY2eD/)**</kbd>

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

**Option 3:**
Set the `font-size` property of `ul` to `0px`

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j72mu/)**</kbd>

```
ul {
    font-size: 0px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The padding on the  element is what does that. Do this:

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

That will completely remove the padding. If you still want SOME padding then adjust the value to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

Change mark up in one line to remove default white-spaces

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
li {
    display: inline; // Change
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPje6/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following css rule to render style

```
li {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    display: table-column-group;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `li` be `font-size: 0;`
and then set the `li a` to normal `font-size`

This way you will make the *whitespace* be 0 pixels wide and keep your html **clean** and easy to read.

Comment: This isn't a hack. It is expected behavior. The whitespace of an inline element is determined by the `font-size`. Simply setting a `font-size` of `0` is not a hack at all. This solution fails if you want to set a `font-size` in `em` units though.