# Why would a div on next line give a little bit of white space?

Tags: html, css

When I position a div on a new line, I get a little white space between the two divs. Why? See this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VBrAM/), with the following code:

```
<div>Welkom</div>
<!--onclick == javascript load projects-->
<div class='menu'>Menu <br />
    <div class='item'>Projects</div>
    <div class='item'>Users</div>
</div><div class='main'><--Click a menu item</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu{
    width: 20%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
.main{
    width: calc(80% - 5px);
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
```

In the example you see that the div with class `main` is directly after the closing tag for the menu div. when I put it on the next line and run it again I get a little white space between the divs. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You must tell the reason why you want to know the reason for white space.Are you trying to remove them or just asking to know?

Comment: to make my html readable I can't have all the text on 1 line. That's why I want a div to begin on a new line. but I get the annoying white space:(

Comment: Look at here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Check my answer on this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805028/how-do-i-remove-li-element-margin/20805177#20805177

Comment: Explains why it happens but how you solves it is not quite right I think. Still I will use the font-size solution I think. thx for the help :)

Comment: If you found the answer yourself don't be afraid to provide an answer yourself (instead of editing it into the question or title). Makes it easier for others to spot the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are spaces there :)
One of the solutions is to write html like this:

```
<div>One<div><!--
--><div>Two</div><!--
--><div>Three</div>
```

So there will be no spaces in browser, because they are commented.