# Annoying white space when creating table in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, whitespace, dreamweaver

I'm fairly new to Dreamweaver and have never taken an IT course in my life, so i'm fairly new to Dreamweaver. I have created a basic website, but I have an issue.

When I insert a table after a Div tag, I position it to overlay on top of the div tag (reason is for formatting purposes that I don't include in the div tag), however There us an annoying piece of empty space after the overlayed div tag and the next item on the website. Any ideas? I'm using Dreamweaver CS6

[image]

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805028/how-do-i-remove-li-element-margin/20805177#20805177 .If the reason is whitespace this may help you

Comment: That doesn't appear to be tabular data, so it shouldn't be in a table.