# CSS left change with jQuery not transitioned

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a pagewide box that can be switched with a previous and next button to create a "timeline" effect.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"><div class="previous">PREVIOUS</div><div class="next">NEXT</div></div>
<div class="pagescontainer">
    <div class="pagesholder" style="left: -0%; transition: all 1s ease;">
        <div id="page1" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page2" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page3" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page4" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page5" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page6" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page7" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page8" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page9" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page10" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page11" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page12" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page13" class="pages"></div>
        <div id="page14" class="pages"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 15%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.previous, .next {
cursor: pointer;
}

.pagescontainer {
position: fixed;
height: 85%;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
transition: left 1s ease;
}

.pagesholder {
position: relative;
left: 0%;
height: 100%;
width: 1400%;
transition: left 1s ease;
display: flex; 
}


.pagesholder.style {
transition: left 1s ease;
}

.pages {

float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#page1 {
background-color: #F00;
left: 0%;
}

#page2 {
background-color: #0F0;
left: 100%;
}

#page3 {
background-color: #00F;
left: 200%;
}

#page4 {
background-color: #FF0;
left: 300%;
}

#page5 {
background-color: #0FF;
left: 400%;
}

#page6 {
background-color: #F0F;
left: 500%;
}

#page7 {
background-color: #666;
left: 600%;
}

#page8 {
background-color: #F00;
left: 700%;
}

#page9 {
background-color: #0F0;
left: 800%;
}

#page10 {
background-color: #00F;
left: 900%;
}

#page11 {
background-color: #FF0;
left: 1000%;
}

#page12 {
background-color: #0FF;
left: 1100%;
}

#page13 {
background-color: #F0F;
left: 1200%;
}

#page14 {
background-color: #666;
left: 1300%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.previous').click(function() {

$('.pagescontainer').hide();
var leftPercentage = $('.pagesholder').css('left');
var leftPercentage = leftPercentage.replace('%', '');
$('.pagescontainer').show();
    var leftPercentage = (leftPercentage) - 100;

$( ".pagesholder" ).animate({
left: (leftPercentage) + '%'
}, 1000);
});




$('.next').click(function() {

$('.pagescontainer').hide();
var leftPercentage = $('.pagesholder').css('left');
var leftPercentage = leftPercentage.replace('%', '');
$('.pagescontainer').show();
    var leftPercentage = parseInt(leftPercentage) + 100;


    alert(leftPercentage);
    $(".pagesholder").css({
        left: (leftPercentage) + '%'
        });
});
```

The transition wont get smooth. If i use `.css()`, the transition doesnt get applied. and the change happens instantly. If i use `.animate()` it has a weird effect the first 3 times, and after that it starts freaking out, worse with every click. I've tried a few variations, but i can't seem to get it working.

The previous button uses the `.animate()` method, the next buttons uses the `.css()` method.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbyEy/8/) for a live example.

The only way it does seem to work, is if i set an alert in the function. For some reason after i click OK on the alert, it animates it just perfectly the way i want it. But i dont want the ugly alert.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbyEy/6/) for a live example.

How can i solve this?

UPDATE:

I need buttons to switch to all pages directly. So for example if id want a button to jump directly to page 3, and want that with the same slide effect, and depending on whether your on page 1 or 2 slide left, or on page 4 slide right. How would i go at making those buttons?

Would it be possible that if your on most left slide, the left button disappears, and when your on the most right slide, the right button disappears? And since its gonna be a timeline, Past, Present, Future. Would it be possible to make it so that say for exmaple page 3 is the "first" page when you would open the site? Then it would be just absolutely perfect!

Comment: Are you ok with a completely different solution with same output?

Comment: On a sidenote, does anyone know why the alert makes my css method do what i want, but when i remove the alert the animation is gone. This just doesnt seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing a completely different solution/code.Hope it will help you:

## ***[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knD6W/1/)***

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
</div>
<div id="nav">
    |<div class="left">Left</div>|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|<div class="right">Right</div>|
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var cont = $('#container');
$('.left').click(function(){
    if(!cont.is(':animated'))
    {
        cont.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft : cont.scrollLeft() - cont.outerWidth()
        },1500);
    }
});
$('.right').click(function(){
    if(!cont.is(':animated'))
    {
        cont.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft : cont.scrollLeft() + cont.outerWidth()
        },1500);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0px;
}
#container *{
    font-size:18px;
}
.item{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.item2{
    background-color:blue;
}
.item3{
    background-color:green;
}
.item4{
    background-color:yellow;
}

#nav{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#nav div{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
    font-family:Ariel,sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

---

### ***[Fiddle with menu for direct navigation to a slide](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/knD6W/2/)***

---

### ***[Fiddle in response to the comment](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/knD6W/5/)***

Comment: Thanks! This looks exactly like what i want. Although since this an entirely different method, im kinda lost about my next step here. My next step would have been i need buttons to switch to all pages directly. So for example if id want a button to jump directly to page 3, and want that with the same slide effect, and depending on whether your on page 1 or 2 slide left, or on page 4 slide right. How would i go at making that button?

Comment: Will do! Thank you so much! I went ahead and already accepted this answer, since its a perfect answer to my original question. But that tweak would be greatly appreciated, and saves creating yet another topic to get that part solved as well;)

Comment: @Jeroen I added a fiddle.Check it

Comment: Perfect! Thank you sooo much! Could i be bold and ask, would it be possible that if your on most left slide, the left button disappears, and when your on the most right slide, the right button disappears? And since its gonna be a timeline, Past, Present, Future. Would it be possible to make it so that say for exmaple page 3 is the "first" page when you would open the site? Then it would be just absolutely perfect! Thanks again for all your help so far, greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Jeroen yup I will update my answer but you will have to make changes in your question also

Comment: I've been working out the navigation menu some further, and thanks to your setup i got it almost all working. I'm stuck on one point though. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/). Everything works, except i cant seem to get the right button for the navigation to disappear when it reached max right. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: Just post me a fiddle with less slides

Comment: Thank you! I made 1 small change, I gave it less scroll per click. Question remains the same. [Fiddle with less slides](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/1/)

Comment: Made change `if(header.scrollLeft()==(header.children('.nav').outerWidth()*40-$(window).width()-5)){..}` for checking right most.I dont know why a blank space is appearing after the end of the small slides sure cause is due to html or CSS.If that is removed use `(header.children('.nav').outerWidth()*39-$(window).width())`.Current fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/4/

Comment: When i check your fiddle, the right nav button doesnt disappear when reaching max right. Also, i dont see the blank space your referring too. And when i try update it with your final suggestion, it breaks and none of the jQuery works anymore...

Comment: try alerting `header.scrollLeft() & (header.children('.nav').outerWidth()*40-$(window).widt‌​h()-5)` within the function.See if they are equal

Comment: Built-in both. The `(header.children('.nav').outerWidth()*40-$(window).widt‌​h()-5)` alert doesnt show at all. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/5/).

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/6/ it is alerting now.See if at the slide end the values are same or not.

Comment: Checked. The values arent the same at the end. Not on any of the clicks btw. 1867:1878 values at end.

Comment: I will add a link of an image.Use it and ask a new question becoz i am getting a blank white space in my fiddle.It is somewhere the problem occuring due to CSS style.If that is solved then the jQuery problem is also solved

Comment: @Jeroen i think i solved the problem.Will post the code within 30 minutes

Comment: That would be awesome! I played with it some more, i can see the effect you mean. When i drag my browser to smaller size, i can reproduce the white space you show in the picture. But i dont have a clue where its coming from or how to fix it...

Comment: Sorry will take a bit more time .Will surely reply as soon as possible

Comment: Finally i have made a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/12/ .Made little changes to HTML,CSS & jQuery .Hope it works now

Comment: It works as long as at maxright it shwows whitespace. Ive played with is some, and if you drag your result box to be taller till the point where it leaves no whitespace, it stops working again. It appears the issue is somewhere in here, since if i drag the resultbox down untill is small enough again so that it produces white space at maxright, it starts working again.

Comment: But in my fiddle no white space is displayed now

Comment: To illustrate: [Working](http://i.imgur.com/NFiwh77.png) and [Not working](http://i.imgur.com/DFqU1RT.png)

Comment: Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m

Comment: That new fiddle same thing. Depending on how tall i drag the result box, and so whether max right show white space or not, it does or don't work.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a question mentioning this issue.And also just to let you know it works in mozilla

Comment: Just ask it this way.Tested on firefox works but not in chrome?

Comment: Doesnt work in IE either. Did you/me use any Firefox specific css? Not that i know off. I also noticed now i tested it in IE that the original question, the big blocks, theres a small stroke on the right, which gets bigger the further you go to the right.

Comment: @Jeroen Its all about the white-space which i dont know why its happening.So ask a question **No white-space in firefox at the end of slide but visible in chrome**

Comment: I will try that tomorrow first thing. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think i found something which could solve the issue. I came across [this](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-determine-if-the-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars-reaches-the-edges/). I tried it in the fiddle, but for some reason i cant get the alert to show, so i cant determine if itll work. If you click the Check Scroll button, it should show an alert. You can help me out why that dont work? Cause i think with this method the css wont matter, cause itll just identify max right, no matter what it is. Check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/19/).

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/20/ .I think it would be better now that create a fiddle for you exactly like you want it

Comment: I see. Maybe [this](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-find-the-html-element-scrollable-height-and-width-using-jquery/) would be a better approach?

Comment: Ok I used your Source and made a fiddle.Tested in chrome at my side.Hope it works now : http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/23 .Just kept the alert also for you to check yourself

Comment: You sheer genius! Tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari. Works in all! Only safari messes up the layout, but all the jQuery still works. So i think ill need to take a look at the css for Safari. The other 4 everything works just perfect! Thank you very much again for all your effort. You have an idea what goes wrong in safari?

Comment: I guess its becoz of white-spaces.I am currently using `font-size:0px` method which removes white-space in all browsers but i guess not in chrome.To see more methods of removing white-space read my answer on this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805028/how-do-i-remove-li-element-margin/20805177#20805177

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain properly. It works PERFECT in Chrome. And also in Firefox, IE and Opera. Only Safari gives problems now. Ill read the Source you gave, maybe i can find a fix in there for Safari. But im really glad it works in the other 4 browsers perfectly now.

Comment: Yes i know what happens in safari.I tested it on safari.I am not talking about that slide end white-space.I am talking about slide inbetween white-spaces only showing in safari not in other browsers.And If you remove them the layout problem occuring in safari may solve.So check my answer on the link I gave you

Comment: The solution was option 0 in the link you gave me, remove all the whitespace in the html. Ill work that out later, but thatll definetly fix it for Safari. Thanks for the link. I was wondering if you could help me out 1 more time. I want a marker in the nav bar. So i created one, but i cant seem to get it working. So ideally i want that marker to be on the nav of the same slide as where the page starts. And then when i click another nav button, it should slide to that nav button. Could you help me out one more time? See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/26/) for demo.

Comment: I would really like to help you but right now I am busy becoz my exams are coming and I have bit of project work to finish .Just ask a new question and post me the page link here in the comment.If your problem doesnt solve I will help you when i get free.

Comment: I was gonna make a new post, but then i found the solution myself.:D Learning lots from you;). Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/27/) to see it in action. Id like to add 1 more function, connecting it also to the normal left and right buttons. Do you know if it is possible to get an elements left value **in vh**? i can get it animated myself now, but i cant change the value with the right amount, cause it keeps giving me the px value, not the vh value.

Comment: [Simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/21/), showing my problem in its core. I want/need it to return 160vh, not 1081.59375px.

Comment: Check this jQuery plugin to get vh like relative values : http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/22/ .Just pass the property and unit and it will calculate and alert the CSS.In this fiddle i have set vw.Change it to vh at both CSS and plugin call

Comment: This definetly looks to what i want. I think theres an error in it somewhere. First i think the /10 doesnt need to be in there, when i run it returns 15, when i remove the /10 it returns 150, as it should. What seems weird is it works with 150, 100 200, and a few more. But for example with 140 or 180 it returns a totally different value. Any ideas? See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/24/) for it working with 150vh example.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/23/) for it not working with 140vh example.

Comment: Also maybe theres an easier way to accomplish what i want. Basically what i need is when i click on left or right, it should add or subtract `12` to/off the current `vh` value for the `left` property of `.marker`

Comment: @Jeroen since this discussion has extended too much ask a new question.I will help you there.Just post me the link

Comment: Your probably right. [New question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169822/add-subtract-fixed-value-to-elements-left-property-set-in-vh-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something on the lines of :

```
var page = 1;


$('.next').click(function() {

if(page ==1 ) {
$('.pagescontainer').hide();
          $('#page1').delay(250).animate({left: '-2200px'},200);
          $('#page2').delay(450).animate({left: '0px'},400);
              page = 2;
} else if(page == 2) {
               $('#page2').delay(250).animate({left: '-2200px'},200);
           $('#page3').delay(450).animate({left: '80px'},400);
               page = 3;
};
```

Ofcourse you have to first put everything on absolute value in css and put it in a container. Now you said you want it from 100% width . There are css codes for that too, I am sure you are aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think Zword's answer is most fitting for what i want to achieve though.