# Add/subtract fixed value to elements left property set in vh with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport-units

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-div{
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 150vh;
bottom: -150px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.vhLeft = function(property,unit){
var wpx = this.css(property).replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"");
var temp = $('<div />').css({
    left:'1'+unit, 
    position: 'absolute'
});
$('body').append(temp);
var oneEm = temp.css(property).replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"");
temp.remove();
var value = wpx/oneEm;
return (Math.round(value*100))+unit;
};
// You could now get your value like
alert($('#my-div').parseInt(vhLeft)('left','vh'));
```

With credits to @Zword.

First off it seems theres something wrong with the function. With some values it works, with some values it doesnt return the right value.

[Example with 150vh](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/24/), working correct.

[Example with 140vh](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/23/), not working correct.

Basically what i need is to be able to add or subtract `12` to/off the current `vh` value for the `left` property of `#my-div` on click of an element.

Comment: ..what? you are only reading the vh value in your example, do you need to set it? why are you generating a temp div?

Comment: and why is 150v => 2vh correct but 140vh => 2vh not?

Comment: @Alex I need to set it according to the current value, so therefor i need that to get working correct first. Also i dont really know how to go at setting it, thats why im asking here. So your right, thats not in there yet, but id like to know how to do so.

Comment: @Alex About the temp div, i wouldnt know honestly, this is the setup Zword gave me. Maybe he can explain better why that temp div is in there. Also i tried to keep the fiddle simple, to show the problem more in its core. If your interested/in case it makes it more clear, [heres a fiddle more towards the end result](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/31/). Basically what i need is if click the normal left or right button, i want the `.marker` to move `12vh` to the left or right.

Comment: @Jeroen do you really want the value to be in **vh** .Why not **px**?

Comment: @Alex Oops, there was a wrong fiddle linked to the second example. Updated original question, second link is now correct fiddle. Does it return 2vh for you? For me first example returns 150vh, second example returns 140206019vh...

Comment: @Zword, if you know how i can get that marker in the right place everytime with px, please let me know. As far as i can see, vh is the only/best way to get it in the right place...

Comment: @Jeroen you know vh is relative to screen.Different on different size screens

Comment: @Zword i know that. But then still 150vh should be 150vh for everyone right, no matter what resolution your on? Just the px value changes, but 150vh is 150vh, right?

Comment: @Jeroen post your timeline fiddle here also mentioning "vh" value is needed for it

Comment: @Jeroen vh and vw values are displayed correctly on mozilla with my fiddle which included `/10`.But on chrome it is giving me `2vh` and similar values

Comment: @Zword posted the timeline fiddle with the marker in it in previous comment, in reaction to Alex. I think this topic makes it pretty clear i need it in vh.

Comment: Looks to me like you're doing it wrong, this should work better -> http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/27/

Comment: @adeneo i guess it is working correctly now.Post it as answer

Comment: @Zword That's  interesting. For me Chrome returns 150vh in your original fiddle with the `/10` removed(else it returns `15vh`). When i run it in Firefox, it returns `0.2vh`, if i remove `/10`, it returns `2vh`. So seems like the other way around for me then for you...  Thats kinda odd isnt it?

Comment: @adeneo That works like a charm. Thank you very much. Could you post it as an answer, so i can accept it, since this answers me original question mainly. Now how do i add or subtract 12 to/off the current vh value for the left property of #my-div on click of an element?

Comment: Just add a setter, give me a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the plugin a little to use `getComputedStyle`, but note that you'll have to polyfill that for IE8 and below, but it will do a better job of returning the correct styles than jQuery seems to do here.

Also, to add a setter, just add another argument and a condition

```
$.fn.vhLeft = function(property , unit, adder){
    var el1 = this.get(0), el2 = document.createElement('div');

    $('body').append(el2);
    el2.style[property] = 1 + unit;

    var px1 = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el1).getPropertyValue(property).replace(/[^0-9\,\.\-]/g, '')),
        px2 = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el2).getPropertyValue(property).replace(/[^0-9\,\.\-]/g, '')),
        tot = Math.round( px1 / px2 );

    if (adder) {
        tot = tot + (adder);
        el1.style[property] = tot + unit;
    }

    $(el2).remove();

    return tot;
};
```

To just get the value you can do

```
var vh = $('#my-div').vhLeft('left','vh');
```

and to add / subtract to the value (this also returns the new value)

```
$('#my-div').vhLeft('left','vh', 12); // adds 12, returns 162

$('#my-div').vhLeft('left','vh', -12); // subtracts 12, returns 138
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/28/)

Comment: I think this is what i need, but i just cant get it in there...:S I need it in something like this: `$( ".marker" ).animate({
            left: vhLeft('left','vh', 12)
        }, 1500);` but this doesnt seem to work... [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/33/) It alerts properly now, but if i click right the black marker still doesnt move...

Comment: @Zword Im kinda lost here... First of all i probably myself set it on the wrong button, it should be on the right button, not the navirght button. Changed that now. But the marker doesnt move... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/35/)

Comment: @Jeroen check my above fiddle.It is moving a bit on clicking right.May be adneo can better answer your problem.ask him

Comment: @adeneo See last few comments. You have any idea how i can get this working(ideally in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/35/))?

Comment: @adeneo [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/37/)  is the closest i got. It applies to the `.marker` when i click the right button, but it just always sets it to 60vh. It doesnt add the 12...

Comment: @Zword i dont see it move in your fiddle. Also when i inspect element it appears it doesnt apply anything to `.marker`. Check my last [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/37/) If you click right and then inspect element on `.marker` you can see it sets left, just always as 60vh, so it doesnt change the value.

Comment: @adeneo Solved. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8YV/38/) Thanks both of you for all your help!