# How can I move a flex element to the middle and maintain some of its previous responsiveness

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a nav bar using a flexbox. I am satisfied, but I think the nav is a little bit on the right side. How can I move it to the left side so that it should have the same responsiveness as before?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 08rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  column-gap: 15rem;
}

.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.main-nav__link {
  padding: 0rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #34495e;
}

.main-nav__link:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.logo__link {
  color: #34495e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">

    <!-- insert logo image -->
    <!-- <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Tolani Logo" class="logo"> -->
    <!-- or -->
    <!-- Use A Logo Image -->
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="/" class="logo__link">Tolani Alumni</a></h1>


    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">College</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">BOk</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <button class="btn btn-login">Login</button>

  </header>
</div>
```

How can I move a flex element to the middle and maintain some of its previous responsiveness

Comment: "As before" you mean as before you started riding a bike or what?  See where we don't have context for that?  What was before?

Comment: ?????NO i mean if add margin  to it move little bit right it;s responsive won't work as it was before . and as you see above it was not covering login section in background color.

Comment: Why don’t you put the logo inside the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made:

- Added: `type="button"`
- Moved CSS: `html { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 62.5%; }` to the top where it cascades better
- Changed `ul` in css to `.main-nav` since I added this list it was "broken" - use classes not element tag for CSS unless you are developing a "library" like bootstrap or the like
- Moved the `.main-nav` CSS all to one place. If you have to have more than one it is likely your CSS needs more work
- Moved `.nav` and `.header` since I prefer top down which is what the C in CSS is about (cascade)
- Changed `.main-nav__link` and `.logo__link` to `.main-nav-link` and `.logo-link` since I hate underscores in CSS because it it hard to tell how many there are and I dislike mixed dash and underscores
- Changed `height: 08rem; to height: 8rem;` because it was more clear
- Removed `.main-nav { margin: 0; padding: 0;` since those were already set above
- Put `*`, with the others instead of a separate group for no reason
- Put `ul.main-nav{ font-size: 0; }` on to deal with margins and put the size on the `li.main-nav-list{ font-size: 2rem; }` ref: [How to remove the default margin of inline li elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20805028/125981)
- `<h1 class="logo"></h1>` was not showing up
- Set `font-size: 16px;` on the html and `body { font-size: 0.625em; }` to set your 10px font since most browsers default to 16px size and 10/16 = 0.625
- Setup a grid with 3 columns and the 8rem height you had

  ```
  header.header {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 5.5rem auto 5.5rem;
      grid-template-rows: 8rem;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 1em;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      padding-right:1rem;
  }
  ```

  after I set the flex (center) to wrap for small screens

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-size: 0.625em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 100vw;
}

header.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5.5rem auto 5.5rem;
  grid-template-rows: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul.main-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
}

.main-nav li.main-nav-list {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.main-nav-link {
  padding: 0rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #34495e;
}

.main-nav-link:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.logo>.logo-link {
  color: #34495e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* not part of your CSS below here */

.body-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-color: #0080FF11;
}
.body-container li{
border: 1px solid #808080;
padding-top: 0.5rem;
padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.body-container code {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="/" class="logo-link">Tolani Alumni</a></h1>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">College</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">BOk</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn btn-login" type="button">Login</button>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="body-container">
  <ul>
    <li>Added: <code>type="button"</code></li>
    <li>Moved CSS: <code>html { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 62.5%; }</code> to the top where it cascades better </li>
    <li>Changed <code>ul</code> in css to <code>.main-nav</code> since I added this list it was "broken" - use classes not elment tag for CSS unless you are developing a "library" like bootstrap or the like</li>
    <li>Moved the <code>.main-nav</code> CSS all to one plac. If you have to have more than one it is likely your CSS needs more work</li>
    <li>Moved <code>.nav</code> and <code>.header</code> since I prefer top down which is what the C in CSS is about (cascade)</li>
    <li>Changed <code>.main-nav__link</code> and <code>.logo__link</code> to <code>.main-nav-link</code> and <code>.logo-link</code> since I hate underscores in CSS because it it hard to tell how many there are and I dislike mixed dash and underscores</li>
    <li>Changed <code>height: 08rem;</code> to <code>height: 8rem;</code> because it was more clear</li>
    <li>Removed <code>.main-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;</code> since those were already set above</li>
    <li>Put <code>*,</code> with the others instead of a separate group for no reason</li>
    <li>Put <code>ul.main-nav{
  font-size: 0;
}</code> on to deal with margins and put the size on the<code>li.main-nav-list{
  font-size: 2rem;
  }</code> ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20805028/125981
      <li><code>&lt;h1 class="logo">&lt;/h1></code> was not showing up</li>
      <li>Set <code>  font-size: 16px;</code> on the html and <code>body {
  font-size: 0.625em;
}</code> to set your 10px font since most browsers default to 16px size and <code>10/16 = 0.625</code></li>
      <li>Setup a grid with 3 columns and the 8rem height you had
        <pre>header.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5.5rem auto 5.5rem;
  grid-template-rows: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right:1rem;
}
</pre> after I set the flex (center) to wrap for small screens</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Stripped down and no ul/li example:
This is the part that matters:

```
header.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1rem 5.5rem auto 5.5rem 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

header.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1rem 5.5rem auto 5.5rem 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

header.header {
  /* same selector as prior but just the visual style parts */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.875em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.875em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.875em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.33em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.33em;
  border-radius: 0.33em;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 2;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.nav {
  grid-column: 3;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

.btn.btn-login {
  /* not really needed but here to be consistent */
  grid-column: 4;
}

.logo>.logo-link {
  color: #34495e;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav .main-nav {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5em;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav .main-nav .main-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34495e;
}

nav .main-nav .main-nav-link:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo"><a href="/" class="logo-link">Tolani Alumni</a></div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="main-nav">
        <div class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Home</a></div>
        <div class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">About</a></div>
        <div class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">College</a></div>
        <div class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Events</a></div>
        <div class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">BOk</a></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn btn-login" type="button">Login</button>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Despite the laundry list of changes, this answer would benefit from a clear explanation of what change(s) solve OP's problem and how.

Comment: grid are good for building nav ? is it worth learning with flexbox ??

Comment: Flex is a single dimension, grid is 2.  I find much of the time that a grid gives you the control you actually desire when laying out full pages; and for headers where you want to position and size "chunks" of it;  Note I used flex to set the center block elements however I did also set it to wrap within that block on smaller screens.  Probably not (yet) a 100% solution here on details of when the three blocks wrap with some minmax etc. - see this reference for some more details perhaps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: FWIW Lots of examples use ul and li elements but then you have to deal with the margins and bullets when a set of div with div children might work easier unless you are nesting a lot of sub menus with dropdowns etc.

Comment: Added second example with no UL/LI and stripped down a lot.  Note I added "fake" columns with `1rem `to the grid for the left/right sizing parts.  Alternate would be padding.  Not sure you need the border radius but that is a "visual taste" thing not part of this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try changing .nav properties to

1. position: absolute;
2. left: 4%;
   You can use trial and error to get the desired results. For maintaining responsiveness I would suggest giving it in %.

Comment: NOT a fan of `position: absolute;` myself since with modern CSS it is very seldom needed and often manifests in MORE CSS to deal with it.

Comment: then padding-left would work just fine, but you have to use media queries for mobile phones

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `position: absolute` is not "very seldom needed with modern CSS". It is a property that achieves a specific thing which is still very much in use when that specific thing is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some minor changes to your code and marked them with comments. Now you can use the gap property of .nav to provide space between the logo and navbar.

Essentially, I have wrapped the logo and nav links within the same container, applied the flex property to it, and added some padding to the header.

You will need to write media queries to make it responsive for other devices.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 4rem; /* left padding added */
  padding-right: 4rem;  /* right padding added */
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 08rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;  /* space-around changed to space-between */
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  column-gap: 15rem;
}

.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lato";
  display: flex;    /* making the nav container flex */
  gap: 5rem;        /* adding gap of 5rem between logo and nav */
  align-items: center;  
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.main-nav__link {
  padding: 0rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #34495e;
}

.main-nav__link:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.logo__link {
  color: #34495e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">

    <!-- insert logo image -->
    <!-- <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Tolani Logo" class="logo"> -->
    <!-- or -->
    <!-- Use A Logo Image -->
    <!-- wrapping logo in nav -->
    <nav class="nav">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="/" class="logo__link">Tolani Alumni</a></h1>


      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">College</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-list"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">BOk</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <button class="btn btn-login">Login</button>

  </header>
</div>
```